# Classic ASP Custom 404 Redirect Isn't Working In Firefox or IE11

Tags: asp-classic, http-status-code-404

I am building a custom 404 response page for a proprietary CMS dedicated to auto/motorcycle sales. The problem I'm running into is that sometimes Google will index a page for a unit that was in the dealer's inventory, but has since been removed, so I'm building a custom 404 page for those instances. My problem is getting the redirect to happen while preserving the 404 status.

The page is written in classic ASP. Long story short, IIS redirects the 404 status to a custom ASP page which I am using to then direct to my 404 page... the idea is that it will display my page only if the 404 comes from a piece of missing inventory and then behaves normally for other pages.

Here's the code that worked in Chrome after days of trying to sort it out:

```
<% 
  Response.Status = "404 Not found"
%>
<script language="JScript" ruant="server">
    window.location = window.location.origin + "/src/xInventory404.asp";
</script>
<%
    Response.End
%>
```

The problem is this doesn't work in Firefox or Internet Explorer 11 unless I remove `Response.Status`, but if I do that I lose the 404 status. I can't just use a `Response.Redirect` because it will lose the 404 and insert a 302 which I don't want for SEO purposes. I have also tried `Server.Execute` and `Server.Transfer`, neither of which worked even in Chrome.

I've been going in circles with this for a couple of weeks now and nothing I've seen on the web has helped so I thought I'd see if anyone here has another idea I can try. Anyone have any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: What is this, whoever thought this was a good idea? IIS has built-in support for custom error pages for a reason.

Comment: No arguments here that it's messy, but it's the system I've inherited. Honestly, if it were up to me I'd just response.redirect the darn thing and be done with it... the sticky wicket is the requirement to have the 404 preserved. I'm trying to do it in a way that works within the parameters I've been given.If what I'm trying to do isn't possible I'm fine with it, but I have to explore all of my options before heading down that road.

Comment: So did you try the custom error page approach in IIS instead of trying to manually force the custom 404?

Comment: IIS already has 404 redirecting to an ASP page. I'm trying to add code to that page that basically says "if the error comes from this specific page, display this nice list of recommended products, otherwise proceed as normal". I have been looking at the idea of doing some kind of conditional redirect within IIS itself, but not seeing a good way to do it so far. I had tried adding a "404.2" to the IIS handler and then telling the inventory page to set the status to that if it couldn't find the item being looked for, but it didn't work.

Comment: You should be able to replace the custom 404 page or at least add to it a conditional check using `Request.ServerVariables("URL")` to check the relative path of the address that triggered the 404 and then either add your content their or use `Server.Transfer()` to load your very specific custom 404 page.

Comment: I notice your JS has the attribute `ruant="server"` by which I asume you mean `runat="server"`. I'm not sure `window.location` would work in server side code because it can't see your browser.  Also be aware that code inside `<script runat="server"></script>` is executed before code inside `<% %>`

Comment: I tried the suggestions y'all made, but still not working. I can't get past the notion that my code works in Chrome and Edge but not Firefox or IE 11... just can't wrap my brain around what would be different there. They work if I remove ```response.status``` from the mix, but then I lose the 404 status on redirect. Frustrating, to be sure... I appreciate all of the input, at this point I think I'm going to go back to the devops folks and see if they have any ideas on how to tweak IIS to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this ended up being a two-fold issue... the issue with Firefox was because I had `<script language="JScript">`, changing that to `<script language="JavaScript">` fixed my problem there... per John's comment, I removed `runat="server"` from the mix, and it would seem the combination of those two things was the secret sauce here.

IE 11 was trickier... turns out the problem wasn't actually my code. IE has a setting to show friendly http errors, when I unchecked that option it also started to work. There's really nothing I can do about client side browser settings so that's kind of a wash, but at least I know what's causing it... and at this point the number of people still using IE 11 should be relatively small so I'm OK with it.

Thanks again for the insights, it really helped to have some different avenues to think about instead of remaining stuck in the circular thinking that brought me here in the first place.

Comment: You still appear to be going about his in a backwards fashion. Make a custom 404 page (triggered by IIS) and use that to show whatever the heck you want.